# How to share notes data with share extension in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, ios-extensions

My application is working fine till iOS 8 But in iOS 9 Beta I am not able to share Notes text/image so can you please suggest me what thinks I need to implement for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Add **NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion** Attributes in your plist file.
```

see this image for reference.

[image]

Comment: For me this only works for plain text. Any idea, which settings to use for a multipart note (e.g. with tables, lists, drawings)?

Answer (score 2):

What to use if I am using NSPredicate for NSExtensionActivationRule?

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>
            SUBQUERY(
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY
            (
            $extensionItem.attachments,
            $attachment,
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.movie"
            ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count == 1
            ).@count > 0
            OR
            SUBQUERY(
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY
            (
            $extensionItem.attachments,
            $attachment,
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg-2000"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.tiff"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.compuserve.gif"
            || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.bmp"
            ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count &lt; 6
            ).@count > 0
</string>
</dict>
```