# Share extension not activates for apple notes app

Tags: ios, ios9, share-extension

My share extension works fine with all apps, except Apple Notes app.
Here is my activation rules:
[image]

Does any body know how to activate share extension for ios9 Apple Notes app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32345379/4475605

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share notes data with share extension in iOS 9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305597/how-to-share-notes-data-with-share-extension-in-ios-9)