# Share extension not activates for apple notes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

Works fine with All the apps except ios Notes App.

Found a solution to solve this

[How to share notes data with share extension in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305597/how-to-share-notes-data-with-share-extension-in-ios-9/32345379#32345379)

But Am  using Subquery as NSExtensionActivationRule. So Unable to add 
NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion in plist.

Is anyone know how to add NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion in subquery ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[image: 1]

The same image i have, as in mentioned answer, just add this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me with Notes.app, News.app, selected text, and urls and pdfs in safari:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
        OR ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.text"
    ).@count >= 1
).@count >= 1
```

Note the `>= 1` which differs from Apple's examples.  Without that it doesn't work for News or Notes.